# How do we add column 2 if column 1 is duplicated multiple times?

Tags: stata

I know how to do it in Excel and have been copying and pasting the data in Excel, using subtotal to add various values and then repasting in Stata. But the dataset I'm dealing with is huge, and it takes 15 minutes in Excel for 1 round. Is there a easier way in Stata?

Answer (score 1):

Without a data example or any attempt at code, the question needs guesswork, not least for anyone who never or hardly ever uses Excel.

Please study https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for hints on what makes a good question.

Columns of a Stata dataset are called **variables**.

You may find this silly example helps. You can type the commands in your own copy of Stata.

If not, you may need to be much more specific about what you are doing. We don't need to see the whole of a huge dataset, just something with similar structure.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. egen totalprice = total(price), by(rep78)

. tabdisp rep78, c(totalprice)

----------------------
Repair    |
Record    |
1978      | totalprice
----------+-----------
        1 |       9129
        2 |      47741
        3 |     192877
        4 |     109287
        5 |      65043
        . |      32152
----------------------

. sort rep78

. list rep78 price totalprice, sepby(rep78)

     +---------------------------+
     | rep78    price   totalp~e |
     |---------------------------|
  1. |     1    4,934       9129 |
  2. |     1    4,195       9129 |
     |---------------------------|
  3. |     2   14,500      47741 |
  4. |     2    5,104      47741 |
  5. |     2    4,010      47741 |
  6. |     2    5,886      47741 |
  7. |     2    3,667      47741 |
  8. |     2    4,172      47741 |
  9. |     2    4,060      47741 |
 10. |     2    6,342      47741 |
     |---------------------------|
 11. |     3    5,222     192877 |
 12. |     3    4,099     192877 |
 13. |     3   15,906     192877 |
 14. |     3    3,895     192877 |
 15. |     3    4,723     192877 |
 16. |     3    4,647     192877 |
 17. |     3   11,385     192877 |
 18. |     3    6,165     192877 |
 19. |     3   10,372     192877 |
 20. |     3   13,466     192877 |
 21. |     3    3,291     192877 |
 22. |     3   13,594     192877 |
 23. |     3    5,172     192877 |
 24. |     3    4,187     192877 |
 25. |     3   11,497     192877 |
 26. |     3    4,296     192877 |
 27. |     3    4,733     192877 |
 28. |     3    4,516     192877 |
 29. |     3    5,788     192877 |
 30. |     3    4,749     192877 |
 31. |     3    4,082     192877 |
 32. |     3    4,181     192877 |
 33. |     3    3,299     192877 |
 34. |     3    4,816     192877 |
 35. |     3    3,955     192877 |
 36. |     3   10,371     192877 |
 37. |     3    5,189     192877 |
 38. |     3    4,482     192877 |
 39. |     3    4,504     192877 |
 40. |     3    6,295     192877 |
     |---------------------------|
 41. |     4    3,829     109287 |
 42. |     4    5,798     109287 |
 43. |     4    4,389     109287 |
 44. |     4    4,890     109287 |
 45. |     4    7,827     109287 |
 46. |     4    3,995     109287 |
 47. |     4    9,735     109287 |
 48. |     4    8,814     109287 |
 49. |     4    6,303     109287 |
 50. |     4    7,140     109287 |
 51. |     4    6,850     109287 |
 52. |     4    4,697     109287 |
 53. |     4    5,705     109287 |
 54. |     4    5,079     109287 |
 55. |     4    4,499     109287 |
 56. |     4    6,229     109287 |
 57. |     4    8,129     109287 |
 58. |     4    5,379     109287 |
     |---------------------------|
 59. |     5    3,748      65043 |
 60. |     5    5,899      65043 |
 61. |     5    5,719      65043 |
 62. |     5   11,995      65043 |
 63. |     5    4,589      65043 |
 64. |     5    5,799      65043 |
 65. |     5    5,397      65043 |
 66. |     5    3,984      65043 |
 67. |     5    9,690      65043 |
 68. |     5    4,425      65043 |
 69. |     5    3,798      65043 |
     |---------------------------|
 70. |     .    3,799      32152 |
 71. |     .    6,486      32152 |
 72. |     .   12,990      32152 |
 73. |     .    4,424      32152 |
 74. |     .    4,453      32152 |
     +---------------------------+
```